# MaxFeretDiameter value using regionprop - Matlab

Tags: matlab

How can I get the MaxFeretDiameter value in the MaxFeretProperties regionprop?

Code:

```
url='http://www.myiconfinder.com/uploads/iconsets/256-256-a0e17c0238c8bd1f805435f7cf132fc1-message.png';

Image = imread(url);
Image = rgb2gray(Image);
Image = imcomplement(Image);

BW = imbinarize(Image);
imshow(BW);
[B,L] = bwboundaries(BW,'noholes');

stat = regionprops(Image,'Centroid', 'MaxFeretProperties' );
disp(stat.MaxFeretProperties);
```

Error :

```
Reference to non-existent field 'MaxFeretProperties'.

Error in Untitled1 (line 17)
disp(stat.MaxFeretProperties);
```

Comment: What is the problem with the code? It looks OK on first reading. Please be specific about what you observed and what you expected. [Edit] your question to include those details.

Comment: How I access the MaxFeretDiameter inside MaxFeretProperties?

Comment: Are you getting an error message when you run the code? If so, please [edit] your question to include that. If not, you should be getting the values you are looking for. What is the problem???

Comment: Added the error

Comment: @elyraz The field is `stat.MaxFeretDiameter`, not `stat.MaxFeretProperties`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feret properties were added to `regionprops` in [MATLAB R2019a](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/release-notes.html?rntext=&startrelease=R2019a&endrelease=R2019a&groupby=release&sortby=descending&searchHighlight=Feret). If your version of MATLAB is older than that, it will not know the `'MaxFeretProperties'` option.

Adding the `'MaxFeretProperties'` option to `regionprops` will add three features to the output struct. You can see this by examining it:

```matlab
>> BW = ~imbinarize(Image);                                % NOTE! invert result so the object pixels are 1 and background pixels are 0.
>> stat = regionprops(BW,'Centroid','MaxFeretProperties'); % NOTE! input binary image here!
>> stat

stat = 

  struct with fields:

               Centroid: [139.3095 124.9653]
       MaxFeretDiameter: 274.7217
          MaxFeretAngle: 132.0492
    MaxFeretCoordinates: [2×2 double]
```

Thus, `stat(ii).MaxFeretDiameter` will give the maximum Feret diameter for object number `ii`.

For those interested in learning more about Feret diameters, I wrote a [blog post](https://www.crisluengo.net/archives/408) many years ago detailing an efficient algorithm to compute it.

Comment: I am running it on 2020a and it does not work also on 2019b

Comment: @elyraz By the way, you might want to do `stat = regionprops(~BW,...)`. This way you get only one object measured in `stat`. When you put the gray-value image in is when you get 255 different objects.